# SPARQL query to get all connected nodes

Tags: sparql

I'm building a sort of rhyming dictionary using a triple store. The triplet data could look like:

```
cat rhymesWith hat
hat rhymesWith bat
sat rhymesWith bat
```

Given some word, I need a SPARQL query that gets all words that rhyme. In other words, given any single node, I need to retrieve ALL nodes that are connected via the rhymesWith predicate, any levels deep and in both directions.

So for any one of the words above, it should retrieve all of the words and de-dupe them.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This might not scale if the whole graph is connected, but you can use SPARQL property path, e.g. `?s (:rhymesWith|^:rhymesWith)* ?o`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately Im using a lightweight js base rdfstore that has not implemented all features of SPARQL 1.1 like property paths. Here are implemented features: https://github.com/antoniogarrote/rdfstore-js#sparql-support

Is there any other way to accomplish this  query?

Comment: Short answer, no. That's exactly what property path `*` operator is for, doing things transitively. Without you would have to know the paths in advance to write the triple patterns which obviously isn't the case here. The only other way would be to run a bunch of queries, i.e. in the client side you do all the things, namely starting from a node, get the neighbors and then for each neighbor get all neighbors and so on and so furth. I'm sure you understand what I mean